# How to sort string of numbers (x,y,z,x,y,..) w/ regular expressions?

Tags: regex, string, notepad++, coordinates

Is it possible to sort string of numbers using regular expressions?

They are separated only by comma (,) the pattern is `xx.xx,-yy.yy,zz.zz,-xx.xx,yy.yy,zz.zz,...`, not necessarily 2 places before and after decimal point and possible minus sign.

(I was hoping to use only primitive macro in Notepad++)

Short excerpt:

```
-50.0,-50.0,30.00012772,-47.47203563,-50.0,29.99892056,-44.94407125,-50.0,30.00167397,-42.41610688,-50.0,29.99915497,-37.31940443,
```

Comment: regex won't do  sorting.

Comment: You cannot use regex to sort matches based on patterns, you could replace `,` by `\n` and then past it to excel and do sorting there

Comment: __This answer should be closed as the OP posted and "answer" that doesn't match the original question, no value for future users.__

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Thanks. But I have also managed to consult it with IT student on my dorms and he figured it out.

```
find: "([+-]*[0-9]+.[0-9]+),([+-]*[0-9]+.[0-9]+),([+-]*[0-9]+.[0-9]+),"

replace: "x=$1 y=$2 z=$3"
```

The magic for me is the **dollar sign plus number** denoting the found expression in given () brackets.

I hope it will help someone else solving the same problem.

Comment: This doesn't sort anything. That isn't an answer to your question.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. You'd be better off copy-pasting the numbers by hand rather than use this 1-time use only expression. Or possibly, the question is misstated.

Answer (score 3):

Regex don't do sorting, it seems that you're using notepad++, being so, to sort lines you can use:

1. click <kbd>Edit</kbd>
2. click <kbd>Line Operations</kbd>
3. click <kbd>Sort Lines in Ascending/Descending Order</kbd>

---

Alternatively, you can use the online tool textmechanic.co for that

http://textmechanic.co/Sort-Text-Lines.html